# How to perform background BLE scanning in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to perform a BLE scan in background continuously every 10 min or so. But most of the users have there Bluetooth switched off. Is there any way to work around this? Can we swtich on and off the BLE

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#setup), the user has to enable it themselves, though you can prompt them to enable it like this:

```
// Ensures Bluetooth is available on the device and it is enabled. If not,
// displays a dialog requesting user permission to enable Bluetooth.
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```